# What was the exact purpose of the device in Regan's ear?

Tags: character, science-fiction, a-quiet-place

In *A Quiet Place*, there was a device like an earbud in the ear of the daughter, Regan, on day 472. Later, her father gives her a new device which she refused at first, but later wore it on her head and ear. To test it, she made a sound with her fingers but apparently she didn't hear anything. I would like to know why - because in a scene, when the alien is near her in farms, there's a sound which irritates her ear and tris to cover her ear, maybe to stop that irritation (and in the end too), so makes me think it *works* or not.

Towards the end, we discover that it creates some sound which irritates the creatures.

In the last scene, she picks up a few items from the table and her mother touches her head to explain something, which I didn't get. (What were those items?)

So what was the purpose of those devices? And what's difference between those two devices, the one she wore before and she wore later?

PS: If possible, kindly don't explain me the ending of movie. I've seen it but I don't want to know what exactly happened (or would happen) in the end of movie.

Comment: A "hearing aid"; https://imsdb.com/scripts/A-Quiet-Place.html

Answer (score 4):

It's a type of hearing aid called a [cochlear implant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochlear_implant).

I'm not a doctor or hearing expert… so straight from Wikipedia…

[image]

> A cochlear implant (CI) is a surgically implanted neuroprosthetic device to provide a person with moderate to profound sensorineural hearing loss a modified sense of sound. CI bypasses the normal acoustic hearing process to replace it with electric signals which directly stimulate the auditory nerve. A person with a cochlear implant receiving intensive auditory training may learn to interpret those signals as sound and speech.

Essentially, a receiver is surgically implanted in the skull and an external transmitter is used to send signals to it, converted from a microphone input.

The daughter, Regan, is shown very early in the plot to be profoundly deaf   and communicates using sign language.  Presumably she had the operation to implant the receiver before the 'quiet time', but either the external transmitter was lost or never supplied.
The father, Lee Abbot, is shown to be looking for potential components to manufacture a transmitter right from the opening scene - showing the audience this has been an ongoing search for a functional system to help his daughter to hear.

[image]

The fact his construction didn't work properly and instead generated audio/radio feedback led to a potential winning move against the aliens, making their ultra-sensitive hearing an impediment or weakness.

At the end she's shown with the ham radio transmitter, hearing aid and a microphone - presumably to be able to transmit the noise across a much wider area.

Comment: umm, tetsujin, the OP asked to not know the purpose at the ending...

Comment: @CGCampbell - I considered it a bizarre request, as basically it's the whole point of the entire plot.

Comment: Ahh, OK. If you want, please roll back my edit.